# How to get the nth word in a string

Tags: java, string, cpu-word

I'm trying to figure out how to get the nth word in a **string** in *Java*. I am stuck on how I should I create the code to do this. A lot of help would nice thanks!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean allCorrect = true;
    allCorrect &= testNthWord("I love to walk to the park", 3, "to");
    allCorrect &= testNthWord("The theater is in the theater district.", 5,
            "the");
    allCorrect &= testNthWord("I am so happy I am getting this right!", 6,
            "am");
    allCorrect &= testNthWord("The quick brown fox jumped over the fence",
            15, "");
    allCorrect &= testNthWord(
            "1 is a lonely number but it also always returns 0 when used before the % operator.",
            1, "1");
    result(allCorrect, "getNthWord");
}

public static String getNthWord(String fullString, int nth) {
    String getIndex;
    for (int i = 0; i < nth - 1; i++) {
        int index = fullString.getIndex(" ");
        if (index == -1)
            return " ";
        fullString = fullString.substring(index + 1);
    }
    int index1 = fullString.getIndex(" ");
    if (index1 = -1)
        return fullString;
    else
        fullString.getIndex(0, index1);
    return "";

}
```

Comment: You can just do a `split` call on the `String` and then get the index of it (nth). but first check if valid index of course

Comment: If you can afford an extra array, use `String#split()`.

Answer (score 1):

Using the .split method you can easily do this. For example:

```
 String[] x = "My Name Is Bob".split(" ");
```

Now you can access the Nth word in the sentence as the Nth position in the array.

The full documentation of the method can be seen [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
boolean allCorrect = true;
allCorrect &= testNthWord("I love to walk to the park", 3, "to");
    allCorrect &= testNthWord("The theater is in the theater district.", 5, "the");
    allCorrect &= testNthWord("I am so happy I am getting this right!", 6, "am");
    allCorrect &= testNthWord("The quick brown fox jumped over the fence", 15, "");
    allCorrect &= testNthWord("1 is a lonely number but it also always returns 0 when used before the % operator.", 1, "1");
    result(allCorrect, "getNthWord");
}
public static String getNthWord(String fullString, int nth)
{
   String[] temp = fullString.split(" ");
   if(nth-1 < temp.length)
   return temp[nth - 1];
   return null;
}
```

This would be the updated code.

Comment: arrays start from zero

Comment: we need to return "return temp[nth - 1];" and also place a check that the length of array is >= nth

Comment: Yep, I saw it as I hit submit. Missed it the first time, but it is corrected now.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps you.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int nth = 5;
        String s = "This is a sample sentence example to test nth numer, lets say 5th.";
        String[] words = s.split("\\s+");
        for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            // you may omit any word you consider is not a word.
            words[i] = words[i].replaceAll("[^\\w]", "");
        }
        System.out.println(words.length);
        if(nth >= 1 && nth <= words.length)
            System.out.println("Nth word is: "+words[nth-1]);

    }
```